# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN при открытии локальных сайтов из wsl2

Tags: google-chrome, wsl2

Имею установленную Wsl2, в которой крутится apache2 сервер, для локальной веб-разработки.
В хост файле windows прописываю адрес:

```
::1 smethno.local
```

Внутри wsl2 в /etc/hosts аналогичный адрес.

При обращении к адресу через firefox всё отрабатывает, и я вижу свой локальный сайт.
Но при попытке обращения через Chrome, выдается код ошибки: **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**.
До какой-то из версий chrome сайт открывался, но после одного из обновлений перестало (более года назад).
По всей видимости, какой-то флайг связанный с DNS препятствует поиску dns имён на локальном компьютере.
Долгий гуглёж, так и не помог.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в hosts файл, сбросил все флаги по умолчанию (вероятно, лишний этап).

```
127.0.0.1 smethno.local
```

После чего хром снова видит локальный сайт.